# First time Python user confused about xlrd error

Tags: python, xlsx, xlrd

I need to make a python script that takes 2 pieces of info from each row of an excel sheet and pastes it into a specific line of a txt file(formatted as c file). I used a lot of online resources to create this but facing this error. I'm a complete beginner to Python so if you could help, I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

```
import xlrd
import os.path

from xlrd import sheet

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join('C:\\Users\\mushtay\\Desktop', 'RDMControls_XCP.xlsx'))
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('ShaftSpeed_SWC')

i = 1

while worksheet.cell(0, i).value == xlrd.empty_cell.value:
    exit()
else:
    Xi = sheet.cell(0, i)
    Yi = sheet.cell(8, i)
    i = i + 1

while i > 1:
    with open("C:\\Users\\mushtay\\Desktop\\Cal0_ROMVariables.c", "r") as f:
        contents = f.readlines()

    contents.insert(17, "Xi-Yi\n")

    with open("C:\\Users\\mushtay\\Desktop\\Cal0_ROMVariables.c", "w") as f:
        contents = "".join(contents)
        f.write(contents)
    i = i - 1
```

These are the errors I'm getting

```
"C:\Users\mushtay\Desktop\Python Project\blegh\Scripts\python.exe" C:/Users/mushtay/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mushtay/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join('C:\\Users\\mushtay\\Desktop', 'RDMControls_XCP.xlsx'))
  File "C:\Users\mushtay\Desktop\Python Project\blegh\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 170, in open_workbook
    raise XLRDError(FILE_FORMAT_DESCRIPTIONS[file_format]+'; not supported')
xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Excel xlsx file; not supported

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: `Excel xlsx file; not supported`, and you're trying to open `RDMControls_XCP.xlsx`.

Comment: Is using `pandas.read_excel` an option for you?

Comment: Welcome.  Pandas is a great and powerful library, but for this it's like using a cannon to kill a fly.  If you are looking to do more advanced stuff with data wrangling in the future, I highly recommend using this as an opportunity to learn Pandas.  Otherwise I would stick to a excel specific library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

per https://pypi.org/project/xlrd/

This library only handles .xls, not .xlsx

It recommends using http://www.python-excel.org/ to find an alternative library.

I am a fan of xlwings so I can put Python directly into my workbooks, but openpyxl and xlsxwriter are great libraries as well.

I do like the work-around of using an older version for one-off, but if this is something to survive long-term or referenced in the future for new code you would probably be better off going to a different library.

Comment: Oh I wasn't aware of that. Thanks for highlighting that.  I will try another library because, as you said, it will be referenced in the future. Thanks for the help Elton!

Comment: No problem.  Everyone was new at something at some point in their lives and this is a great community.  I get my questions answered here, and are now less trivial as a result, and try to do the same for people who are in the shoes I was once in.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pip install xlrd==1.2.0
```

It will be good for your issue

Comment: Ahh this worked for me! Thank you! But it seems after speaking to a coworker that because other people would be using the script, I may need to find a better solution. Thank you for your suggestion though!